# What is the purpose of .to in Chai Library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I don't get the purpose of [to](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) in chai api.
For example, I found if I didn't use **to** my cases still pass. So is it just added to improve readability? I guess my question is, is it the **only** purpose?

```
//use to
expect(result).to.equal('baba');
expect(result).to.have.property('baba');

//do not use to. 
//As a non-native English speaker, I prefer typing less
expect(result).equal('baba');
expect(result).have.property('baba');
```

Comment: `.to` is a language chain to improve readability

Comment: Is that the only purpose ?

Comment: Yes it is. I referenced chai library documentation.

Comment: Can you paste the link?

Comment: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_language-chains

Comment: That is the one I embedded in my question. But I didn't find it said that was the only purpose.

Comment: It'd be bad practice to say that it's intent is one thing and expect its behaviour to be different from its documentation. I suppose diving into the source code may reveal an alternative purpose but I highlight doubt that.

Answer (score 2):

> The following are provided as chainable getters to improve the
>   readability of your assertions. to, be, been, is,...

Yes this `.to` is for the readability and specially those are chainable, it means there is no difference of

```
expect(result).to.equal('baba'); // with .to

expect(result).to.to.to.to.to.equal('baba'); // with .to x 5

expect(result).equal('baba'); // without .to
```

Since `.to` doesn't change object properties

Hope you got the idea